# read file, dropped to Chrome Extension popup window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

is it possible to read the contents of file that was dropped to chrome extension popup window? my goal is to create extension which would help to fill out some web-form. you just need to drop the text file to the extension window and then the contents of file will be auto-inserted to web form. i know that chrome app can get access to the file system, but i am working with extension. and my file is dropped by user. I've already dealt with "drag'n'drop" and with web-page contents replacement.

**Update**
my extension is works fine now, big thanks to @wOxxOm. i use

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsText(file);
reader.onloadend = function() {
    content = this.result;
}
```

for file reading and

```
chrome.tabs.query({"status":"complete","windowId":chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,"active":true}, function(tabs){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, content);
    });
```

for sending file contents to content script.

but i use text file as input now. my text file contains JSON and looks like

```
{
    "surname": "Smith",
    "name": "John",
    "select1": "value 3",
    "email": "a@b.com",
}
```

when i drop this file to my extension's popup, it scans web page for input fields (jquery name selector) with names from this JSON, and fills this fields with values from JSON. so its automated form filling tool and it can be used with any web site :)
the next problem is to use `.docx` files as input. i know that `.docx` is simple `.zip`, so i can unpack it and then read the document's contents. but i need to save the file first, unpack it to extensions's folder and then read the unpacked files. i use this code for request sandboxed filesystem access:

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
  console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

but it seems that only google apps can get access to sandboxed file system. what i am doing wrong? i dont want to get access to the local file system. i think that `chrome.storage` is not suitable as it allows you to store key-value items.

Comment: In the popup's `drop` event listener read the file using FileReader API into a `Blob`, there are lots of examples of doing that. Then get URL.createObjectURL, send the result in a message to your content script, where you'll read it using fetch() into a `Blob`. Then override or prevent the site's submit event and submit the form's data yourself using XMLHttpRequest and `FormData` API where you can assign the blob freely. There's a lot of moving parts so try finding an existing extension to use as a sample.

Comment: @wOxxOm the FileReader works fine! sorry for such stupid question, i thought that some fileSystem permissions were required, but the solution was simple) thank you!

Comment: @wOxxOm so now i can read) I will deal with the transfer of data to the content script.